# Printing the pixel values of YUV image

Tags: image, opencv, yuv

When i convert a image to `YUV` from `RGB` I cant get a value of Y when I try printing the pixels. I get a value `377` and when I cast it with integer I get 255. WHich I presume is incorrect. Is there a better way or rather correct way to print the values of YUV image pixels.

Actually i am priting the values `(int)src.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0]= 255` 
and `src.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0] = 377`

Also on that note, the Y is the combination of RGB calculated with some constants according to note. I am actually confused as how to get the value of Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of OpenCV. OpenCV does not gracefully handle (scale) YUV or HSV color spaces for `uchar` format. With `Vec3b` you have effectively 3-channel `uchar`, and that ranges [0;255].

The solution is to use another matrix type. With `cv::Mat3f` you have a 3-channel floating point image. Then the values will be correctly converted by `cvtColor` function. You can get a Mat3f from a Mat3b by assignment.

Another solution that uses less memory may be Mat3s and Mat3w types, if supported by cvtColor.

Comment: Ok i see the problem of OpenCV. imread() by default is uchar i guess. So you meant i convert from uchar type of Mat3f. Did i get that correct.

Comment: Yes, or you just do Mat3f input = imread(…), it works. However if imread fails (e.g. wrong filename) it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for you help. One more question, like u suggested that i use Mat3f to directly read the image. It works but when i print the image it shows all white however when i do cvtColor, it shows the object well. Now my confusion is that when i read as Mat3f is it transformed form uchar to float automatically.

Comment: imshow assumes range [0;255] for uchar images, but range [0;1] for float images. If you want to imshow the image just after reading, call imshow(image/255.).

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you, but may be you could answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985343/opencv-how-to-get-pixels-yuv-values-instead-of-its-bgr-ones) of the same topic ?